# Ampersand inside double quote sed command produces different output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, debian

Can someone please explain to me why these 3 commands produce different outputs?

```sh
printf "%s"  `echo ../.. | sed 's/[.]/\\&/g'`
printf "%s" $(echo ../.. | sed 's/[.]/\\&/g')
printf "%s" "$(echo ../.. | sed 's/[.]/\\&/g')"
```

Comment: They don't.  For me, all of them write `&&/&&` (after adding the missing backtick on the first.). Which command gives you something different?  I guess you are seeing `../..` for one of them.

Comment: They all produce the same output.

Comment: The results are really different - https://ideone.com/8d4aQg

Comment: Backticks are expected to change how backslashes (and other backticks) behave within them. It's documented and normal, and is part of why `$( )` is preferred instead.

Comment: As always, you should use `set -x` to enable tracing when trying to figure out how your code is interpreted by a shell. See https://ideone.com/VLLNql showing Wiktor's link with that tracing active.

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM, if backticks didn't change how backslashes behave within them, they wouldn't be nestable (that is to say, if these three lines all had the same output, there would be no backtick-based equivalent to `echo $(echo hello $(echo world) )` possible).

Comment: ...see also [BashFAQ #82](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) and the links therein (including to [section 2.6.3 of the POSIX sh specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03)).

Comment: consider updating the question with the output generated by your code; I get the same output as per Wiktor's link

Comment: this is the ouput: ++ echo ../..
++ sed 's/[.]/\&/g'
+ printf %s '&&/&&'

++ echo ../..
++ sed 's/[.]/\\&/g'
+ printf %s ../..

++ echo ../..
++ sed 's/[.]/\\&/g'
+ printf %s '\.\./\.\.'